# Overtone & Vim (Repl doesn't seems to be connected)

Tags: vim, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I tried to play with overtone on ubuntu, but I can't eval some of overtone's codes in Vim.

:Eval works for the clojure code; I tried it in vim (a clj file in the lein project directory), ex: (+ 1 2 3) => :Eval => appeared on the bottom of the vim window => 6, so it's ok.

But, for example, I tried:

```
(demo(sin-osc)) => :Eval ;(:Require don't change nothing)
```

It returned:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: demo in this context, comp
iling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

So here's what I do:

- jack is started
- lein repl is started in the lein project (deps is ok)
- in the first terminal where there is lein I start overtone (use 'overtone.live), here is the log; I've got 2 errors:

  user=> (use 'overtone.live)
  --> Loading Overtone...
  --> Booting internal SuperCollider server...
  *** ERROR: dlsym load err '/home/axxon/workspace/overtone/tutorial/native/linux/x86_64/libscsynth.so: undefined symbol: load'
  Found 10 LADSPA plugins
  *** ERROR: open directory failed '/home/axxon/.local/share/SuperCollider/synthdefs'
  JackDriver: client name is 'SuperCollider'
  SC_AudioDriver: sample rate = 44100,000000, driver's block size = 1024
  --> Connecting to internal SuperCollider server...
  --> Connection established
  JackDriver: max output latency 23,2 ms
- here, in this window I tried (demo(sin-osc)). it works; I can hear it.
- Great, but now I want to script with Vim, so I created a new file (mytest.clj) in the lein project directory (/overtone/tutorial), I opened it with Vim (in another window)
- in this blank file, I wrote the same thing as I said before, (demo(sin-osc)) and tried to eval with first, :Require, it returned this:

  (clojure.core/require 'user :reload)

  ```
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate user__init.class or user.clj on 
  classpath:
  ```
- with Eval, it doesn't work either.

Thanks for your help because I really want to use overtone!

Ps: my vim bundles:

Bundle 'guns/vim-clojure-static' 
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fireplace' 
Bundle 'tpope/vim-classpath'

Edit: I forgot to use a correct namespace, and in overtone's google group, i seen that mytest.clj must be in the  src directory of the project. I tried this code with :Require (i stopped overtone in the first window where i started lein):

```
(ns tutorial.foo
  (:use [overtone.live]))
(definst saw-wave [freq 440 attack 0.01 sustain 0.4 release 0.1 vol 0.4]
      (* (env-gen (lin-env attack sustain release) 1 1 0 1 FREE) (saw freq) vol))
(saw-wave)
```

, but it returned:

```
(clojure.core/require 'tutorial.foo :reload)
Erreur détectée en traitant function <SNR>17_Require..fireplace#session_eval..<S
NR>17_eval..7 :
ligne   38 :
E605: Exception non interceptée : Error running Clojure: *** ERROR: open directo
ry failed '/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64'^@*** ERROR: dlsym load err '/usr/lib/jn
i/libswt-gtk-3836.so: undefined symbol: load'^@*** ERROR: dlsym load err '/usr/l
ib/jni/libswt-glx-gtk-3836.so: undefined symbol: load'^@*** ERROR: dlsym load er
r '/usr/lib/jni/libswt-webkit-gtk-3836.so: undefined symbol: load'^@*** ERROR: d
lsym load err '/usr/lib/jni/libswt-atk-gtk-3836.so: undefined symbol: load'^@***
 ERROR: dlsym load err '/usr/lib/jni/libswt-pi-gtk-3836.so: undefined symbol: lo
ad'^@*** ERROR: dlsym load err '/usr/lib/jni/libswt-cairo-gtk-3836.so: undefined
 symbol: load'^@*** ERROR: dlsym load err '/usr/lib/jni/libswt-awt-gtk-3836.so: 
undefined symbol: load'^@*** ERROR: dlsym load err '/usr/lib/jni/libswt-gnome-gt
k-3836.so: undefined symbol: load'^@#^@# A fatal error has been detected by the 
Java Runtime Environment:^@#^@#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5d261db671, pid=693
1, tid=140036632291072^@#^@# JRE version: 7.0_25-b30^@# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bi
```

Comment: Have you tried using the one true editor?

Comment: :D do you speak about Emacs ?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. It turned out that the vim fireplace plugin was not connected to my bash repl session. I manually established the connection and everything worked just fine afterwards.

At the top of your lein session you should see the details about what port the repl session is running on

`nREPL server started on port 35182 on host 127.0.0.1`

So then you can connect vim-fireplace to that repl session by using

`:Connect nrepl://localhost:35182`

The reason why you can still evaluate code like `(+ 1 2 3)` even when vim-fireplace is not connected to the remote repl session is because vim-classpath will make it fall back to just spawning a new clojure runtime instance to evaluate that code. Once the fireplace repl connection is working you should notice that evaluating code becomes a lot faster since it doesn't need to load clojure from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you use overtone.live in the namespace declaration of the file you are editing in vim, and that the REPL is running in a separate terminal instance. From vim, save the file (:w) and move your cursor into the ns declaration. Then hit gf to open the file for the namespace. Type cpR or :Require! and then cpp or :Eval the function you were trying to run. Hopefully this will work for you! Best of luck.

Comment: Thx a lot ! I try, in /tutorial/src/tutorial/foo.clj to open overtone.live in my namespace with gf but no success: (ns tutorial.foo (:use [overtone.live]). It returned, 'Couldn't find file for'. What's wrong ? (lein deps is ok, normaly ...)

Comment: That is unusual. Double check that both clojure and overtone are listed as dependencies in your project.clj file in the /tutorial folder. If they are, try running lein deps again from /tutorial folder and get a REPL running again. When you open foo.clj in vim again make sure your cursor is in the WORD tutorial.foo when you hit gf. Again, good luck. Troubleshooting is hard.